# For what $b$ does $\sin^2(x) - \cos(bx) + 1=0$ has only one solution?

Tags: calculus

For what $b$ does $f(x) = \sin^2(x) - \cos(bx) + 1=0$ has only one solution, if possible?

First, I noticed that $x=0$ is a root. If the equation has only one solution, then a sufficient condition would be that $f(x)$ is monotonic on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, which is not the case here. Also, I know that if $b=0$, then $f(x)$ has infinitely many solutions.

A plot seems to suggest that no such $b$ exists. But how should I prove it?

Comment: Did you try irrational values of $b$?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ iff $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(bx)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that $1-\cos(2a)=2\sin^2a$ so that the equation becomes
$$
\sin^2x+2\sin^2\frac{bx}2=0
$$
which means that you have to avoid that $x$ and $\frac b2x$ are simultaneously integer multiples of $\pi$. So chose $b$ as any irrational number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint convert everything to $\cos $ and then get the equation as $\cos^2 (x)+cos (bx)-2=0$ then differentiate to get derivative as $-sin (2x)-b\sin (bx) $ now all depends on $bx $ ie to which quadrant it belongs ie whether son is positive or negative thus monotonicity cant be assured thus the f (x) has more than 1 solution.